# Python: how to create square buffers around points with a distance in meters

Tags: python, gis, geopandas, shapely

I have a geopandas dataframe `gdf`

```
gdf
    ID  longitude   latitude    geometry
0   80  103.619501  1.2810      POINT (103.619500987 1.281)
1   81  103.619501  1.2855      POINT (103.619500987 1.2855)
```

Following [this suggestion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314949/creating-square-buffers-around-points-using-shapely) I create a square buffer around it with a distance `bd` defined as:

```
bd = abs((gdf['latitude'][0]-gdf['latitude'][1])/2)
```

And finally I am able to get the following:

```
buffer = gdf.buffer(bd)
envelope = buffer.envelope

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7.5, 7.5))
envelope.plot(color='white', edgecolor='gray',ax=ax)
gdf.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

How can I set a distance `bd` that corresponds to 500 meters?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57284066/calculate-geographical-distance-between-5-cities-with-all-the-possible-combinati/57287599#57287599 Does this link help?

Answer (score 7):

You need to reproject your data to CRS which uses meters as coordinates. As you are using longitude and latitude, your values are in degrees. All, including buffer distance. If you want to do square buffer, you do not need to use envelope, just set `cap_style` to 3 (see [shapely docs](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.buffer)).

```
gdf.crs = 'epsg:4326' # I am assuming here
gdf = gdf.to_crs(epsg=3395)

buffer = gdf.buffer(500, cap_style=3) # you might want to use 250, guessing from your image
```

For more details I recommend [geopandas user guide](http://geopandas.org/projections.html).

Comment: Do you loss the attribute table information after doing the buffering of points?

Comment: Not if you assign the GeoSeries containing buffer as a column. Either to replace original `geometry` column or a new one.

Answer (score 2):

this is my function, which have high precision. data is a DataFrame,which contain a `shapely`'s geometry type

```py
def generate_buffer_meter(data, radiu, geometry='geometry', crs='epsg:4326'):
    data = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, geometry=geometry, crs=crs)
    data = data.to_crs('+proj=aeqd +units=m  +x_0=0 +y_0=0')
    data[geometry] = data[geometry].buffer(radiu)
    data = data.to_crs(crs)
    return data
```

Comment: your method returns circle, not square. You may use `cap_style=3` as in answer above

Comment: I think you want .to_crs(epsg=3395)  instead of aeqd.  And, .buffer(radiu,cap_style=3)